# Best array manipulation API

Tags: z3

The SMT-LIB 2.0 array initialization and manipulation is a bit cumbersome. As the following code explains, http://rise4fun.com/Z3/kxmrd.

Is there any elegant way to initialise or manipulate arrays, using Python/C/C++/.Net API than SMT-LIB 2.0 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use regular Python constructs such as `for i in range(n)` to achieve what you want:

```py
s = Solver()
a = Array('a', IntSort(), IntSort())
xs = [20, 23, 27, 12, 19, 31, 41, 7]

for i in range(len(xs)):
  s.add(Select(a, i) == xs[i])

a1 = Array('a1', IntSort(), IntSort())

s.add(a1 == Store(a, 3,9 ))

print s.check()

m = s.model()
for d in m.decls():
  print "%s = %s" % (d.name(), m[d])
```

Run it online [here](http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/Kg7).

It would be nice if you could write something like `s.add(a == xs)` or `s.add(a.startsWith(xs))`, but I don't know if that is possible.